# Accessing the placeholder attribute

Tags: javascript

```
    window.onload = function(){
        var inputElement = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        console.log(inputElement);
        console.log(inputElement.hasAttribute('placeholder'));
        if(inputElement.hasAttribute('placeholder')){
            console.log('true');
        }
    };
```

I keep getting a an TypeError on window.onload. Could someone point whats wrong with this, i am trying to to check if an input element has a placeholder attribute

Comment: Look closer: it's getElement**s**ByTagName - plural.

Comment: As in you have an *array* of elements, not the element itself. You need to loop through and check each one.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Why getElementsByClassName does not work for me? What does it return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/why-getelementsbyclassname-does-not-work-for-me-what-does-it-return) (but this is for `getElementsByTagName` instead of `...ClassName`)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName
```

returns an array or nodelist or whatever so you need to access its elements. What you're trying to do is run `hasAttribute` on the list, which apparently doesn't have such a function.

What you want is

```
var inputElement = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
```

also if there are no input elements this will throw an error that there is no `0` index or something

Comment: Specifically, it returns a [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

Comment: Yeah that was the one I couldn't think of so I wrote whatever instead :D

Comment: yep @php_nub_qq i had a feeling it had to do something with HTMLCollection , thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to collect all of the inputs and look for placeholders,  loop through the inputs that you've collected in `inputElement` and check each one.

I'd suggest something like this (though, I'd also recommend something in the log to indicate which inputs test positive for a placeholder   ;)   ):

```
window.onload = function() {
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for (i = 0; i < inputElements.length; i++) {
        if (inputElements[i].hasAttribute('placeholder')) {
            console.log('true');
        }
    }
};
```

If you need to access a specific one, then you are going to have to figure out a way to identify the `input` uniquely (e.g., with an `id` attribute).  Then you could use the approach that you are trying:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var inputElement = document.getElementById('some_id_value');

    if (inputElement.hasAttribute('placeholder')) {
        console.log('true');
    }
    else {
        console.log('false');
    }
};
```